# Handling duplicate symbols for peripheral registers when testing embedded C++ code using googletest

Tags: c++, embedded, googletest

I'm developing a hobby project for MSP430F5529 using C++ and testing using googletest. I'm a true beginner both at C/C++, microcontrollers/embedded and googletest.

The peripherals on the MSP are controlled via registers and TI provides a header `<msp430.h>` that includes a processor specific header, `msp5529.h`, in my case and that header defines a large number of constants for bits etc but it also declares the registers available on the microcontroller for example `UCA1CTL1`used to setup serial communication.

When I compile for build `<msp430.h>` is included in `UART.h` for example and everything works as intended. When testing however I want to include a testable version of `<msp430.h>` which we can call `testable_msp430.h`.

So basically we have the following:

**UART.h**

```
#ifndef TESTING
#include <msp430.h>
#else 
#include "testable_msp430.h"
#endif
```

**testable_msp430.h**

```
int UCA1CTL1;

*A bunch of other declarations*
```

**test_UART.cpp**

```
#include UART.h

*A bunch of tests*
```

**UART.cpp**

```
#include UART.h

*A bunch of source*
```

The problem is that when compiling this for test by running `g++ -std=c++11 src/UART.cpp test/test_UART.cpp -lgtest -lgtest_main -pthread -o testOutput -DTESTING` I get a link error stating

```
duplicate symbol _UCA1CTL1 in:
    /var/folders/yr/mkwg3mhs1nl93l35x6t55vz80000gn/T/UART-772fab.o
    /var/folders/yr/mkwg3mhs1nl93l35x6t55vz80000gn/T/test_UART-2e1a90.o
```

which makes sense since `UCA1CTL1`is defined in both the compilation unit for `UART.cpp`and `test_UART.cpp`. My question is therefore how memory mapped registers are usually handled to be able to test against/using them?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: .ccp is an unconventional filename extension for C++, not one of those recognised by gcc:  http://labor-liber.org/en/gnu-linux/development/index.php?diapo=extensions

Comment: It is laudable that you take unit testing so seriously, but as both a hobby project and a beginner, I might suggest that learning C++, embedded systems and GoogleTest all at the same time seems rather ambitious.

Comment: Ah, should have been cpp. Thanks for pointing it out and I edited the question! And yes it's a bit of a challenge but I have a colleague who does embedded work so I can always bug him about issues on weekdays :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have *definitions* rather then *declarations* in testable_msp430.h.  Rather than:

```
int UCA1CTL1;
```

you should have:

```
extern int UCA1CTL1;
```

Then in another translation unit linked only to the test or wrapped in `#ifndef TESTING`, or within test_UART.cpp, you place the *single* test definition of `UCA1CTL1` *et al*.

Comment: Yep! Extern in the header and then a cpp file were they were declared solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things:

- Use header guards. testable_msp430.h should look like

  ```
  #ifndef TESTABLE_MSP430_H
  #define TESTABLE_MSP430_H
  /* contents */
  #endif
  ```
- Don't declare variables in headers. If you need to share them across multiple files, all variables in the header should be `extern` and they should be allocated in the .c file with the same name as the header.
- `int UCA1CTL1;` for a register is nonsense. If the linker allocates this variable at the correct memory location for you, it should be `volatile uint8_t UCA1CTL1;` (assuming 8 bit registers). If the linker doesn't link it at the specific, correct memory location, you could consider using a portable macro instead of a variable:

  ```
  #define UCA1CTL1 (*(volatile uint8_t*)0x1234u)
  ```

  where 0x1234 is the address of the register. This also resolves the linker hiccups that you get from allocating variables in a header file.

  Macros like these are the only way to get fully portable register maps across multiple compilers. The downside is that you won't get an actual object in the file passed to the debugger, so you can't watch the macro like you would with a variable.

  However, any half-decent microcontroller debugger comes with hardware support for all peripherals, allowing you to view registers from there, so it isn't an issue as long as you don't plan to use trash quality debuggers.

Comment: Yep! I have include guards in the headers but omitted them here for brevity. They didn't help me in this case though since they only work in each compilation unit. I.e. when my two cpp files included the same h file they didn't help me.

Your second point is what worked.

My definitions are just for testing on the host so I only need a variable in which i can set specific bits and check that they are set, for now at least. The regular <msp430.h> header handles the actual memory adresses when building for the target.